# Subtracting the last data with zero and the first data with 1 after that, for each group

Tags: r, dplyr

Sorry if the title looks confusing. In the following data,

```
mydata<- data.frame(id= c("1","2","1", "1" ,"2" ,"1"), transaction = c (0,0,1,0,1,1) , time = c( 10, 20, 22, 27, 39, 47))
```

I have some **visits** ( when transaction = 0) and I have some **transactions** where (transaction =1). I wish to know the time difference between the **last visit** and the **transaction** for **each id** : For instance, the last time that id one had a visit was in time 10 befor his transaction that happened in time 22 which have 12 unit difference. 
This is my data

```
  id transaction time
1  1           0   10
2  2           0   20
3  1           1   22
4  1           0   27
5  2           1   39
6  1           1   47
```

And I wish to have the following output:

```
   id transaction time  dif
1  1           0   10   NA
2  2           0   20   NA
3  1           1   22   12
4  1           0   27   NA
5  2           1   39   19
6  1           1   47   20
```

I have tried something like that which is obviously wrong

```
library(dplyr)
%>%
group_by( id) %>%

mutate(  dif =first(time[transaction == 1])-last(time[transaction == 0]))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `data.table` with the assignment (`:=`) in place to avoid any copying

```
library(data.table)
setDT(mydata)[, dif:=time[transaction!=0]- time[transaction==0], 
                               by = id][transaction==0, dif:= NA][]
```

#### Update

There was one value that was not matching earlier.  The below code fixes it

```
setDT(mydata)[, ind := cumsum(c(TRUE, diff(transaction==1)<0)),
 id][, dif := time[transaction==1]-time[transaction==0], .(id, ind)
    ][transaction==0, dif:= NA][, ind := NULL][]
#    id transaction time dif
#1:  1           0   10  NA
#2:  2           0   20  NA
#3:  1           1   22  12
#4:  1           0   27  NA
#5:  2           1   39  19
#6:  1           1   47  20
```

Answer (score 1):

```
df %>% group_by(id) %>% mutate(time1 = ifelse(transaction!=0,time-time[1],NA))

#      id transaction  time time1
# <int>       <int> <int> <int>
# 1     1           0    10    NA
# 2     2           0    20    NA
# 3     1           1    22    12
# 4     1           0    27    NA
# 5     2           1    39    19
# 6     1           0    47    NA
```

Comment: But it is not correct for the last row and I don't get what `time-time[1]` is

Comment: the last row in my data ha stransaction = 0 . so that has confused you i guess. I shall edit my data

Answer (score 1):

With base R (assuming that each id has at least one observation with transaction = 0 and one with transaction=1)

```
 mydata$dif <- NA
 mydata$dif[mydata$transaction==1] <- unlist(lapply(split(mydata, mydata$id), function(x) x$time[x$transaction==1] - x$time[x$transaction==0][1]))

 id transaction time dif
1  1           0   10  NA
2  2           0   20  NA
3  1           1   22  12
4  1           0   27  NA
5  2           1   39  19
6  1           0   47  NA
```

Answer (score 1):

This is an option too-

```
mydata<- data.frame(id= c("1","2","1", "1" ,"2" ,"1"),
                transaction = c (0,0,1,0,1,1) ,
                time = c( 10, 20, 22, 27, 39, 47))

id_types <- levels(factor(mydata$id))

mydata$dif <- rep(0, nrow(mydata))
lapply(temp, function(x, data = mydata) 
       {
        mydata[mydata$id == x, "dif"] <<-
        c(0,diff(mydata[mydata$id == x, "time"], 1)) *
        (seq(0,length(mydata[mydata$id == x, "time"])-1) %% 2)
       })
mydata[mydata$dif == 0, "dif"] <- NA
```

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
library(dplyr)

mydata<- data.frame(id= c("1","2","1", "1" ,"2" ,"1"), transaction = c (0,0,1,0,1,1) , time = c( 10, 20, 22, 27, 39, 47))

mydata$dif <- sapply(1:nrow(mydata), function(i) ifelse(mydata$transaction[i]!=0,mydata$time[i]-tail(filter(head(mydata,i-1),id==as.numeric(mydata$id[i]))$time,1),NA))
```

output mydata

```
  id transaction time dif
1  1           0   10  NA
2  2           0   20  NA
3  1           1   22  12
4  1           0   27  NA
5  2           1   39  19
6  1           1   47  20
```